# i tried to clone into snort3 but it didn't work anyone could help me?

Tags: git, ubuntu, security, snort, ids

j'ai tapé git clone https://github.com/snortadmin/snort3.git il m'affiche error rpc failed; curl 92 http/2 stream 0 was not closed error 1294 bytes of body are stil excpected fata: fetch- pack: invalid index output

j'ai tapé git clone https://github.com/snortadmin/snort3.git il m'affiche error rpc failed; curl 92 http/2 stream 0 was not closed error 1294 bytes of body are stil excpected fata: fetch- pack: invalid index output g